# there is syntax error occurs when i put order by in the code

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT ​* ​FROM ​car_details ​ORDER BY ​ApproxPrice ​;
```

> ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '​ORDER BY ​ApproxPrice ​' at line 1

Comment: If you look at a copy/paste of your query in dbfiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6CRv6XqYMAfkBHEBhz1zGe/2), you can see that you're using some weird space character

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing extra-spaces before ';' and give space between select,* and FROM. the query looks fine.